# Mocking Java Spring Test - NullPointerException

Tags: java, mocking

I am new to testing with mocks and I am trying to test a method on a controller, however I get NullPointerException. Here is my controller method:

```
    //CREATE MARK
@RequestMapping(value = "/marks", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createMark(@RequestBody MarkDTO markDTO) {
    markService.createMark(markDTO);
}
```

Here is my service:

```
public interface MarkService {

Page<MarkDTO> getMarks(Pageable pageable);
MarkDTO getMark(Integer id);

void createMark(MarkDTO markDTO);
void updateMark(Integer id, Mark mark);
void deleteMark(Integer id);
```

}

And this is my test:

```
public class MarkControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext ctx;

@Mock
private MarkService markService;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup(){

}

@Test
public void createMark() throws Exception {


   //doNothing().when(markService.createMark(markDTO));
    mockMvc.perform(post("/marks")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("{\n" +
                    "  \"id\": 1,\n" +
                    "  \"id_profesor\": 2,\n" +
                    "  \"valoare\": 10,\n" +
                    "  \"data_notare\": \"2017-05-29\"\n" +
                    "}"));
}
```

}

If I un-comment the doNothing line, I get an error, something like T Stubbed can't be applied to void.

I am not sure how to mock my service, however I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.fiivirtualcatalog.modules.homework.controllers.MarkControllerTest.createMark(MarkControllerTest.java:66)

Any idea where I migh t be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not foget to declare controller you whant to test inside test class, and call this inside your @Before method:

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
```

And second one, to prevent error of mocking markService method call you need to use below code:

```
doNothing().when(markService).createMark(markDTO);
```

instead of:

```
doNothing().when(markService.createMark(markDTO));
```